# How to select highest among most frequent number in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In this below example how do we set mode to 2 instead of 1. Basically if there are two instances of most frequent occurring number, how do we select the highest among them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Excel 2010 or later versions**, presume your data is stored in `A2:E2`, try one of the following:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,MODE.MULT($A$2:$E$2),1)
```

or

```
=MAX(MODE.MULT($A$2:$E$2))
```

or

```
=LARGE(MODE.MULT($A$2:$E$2),1)
```

Comment: I like the 2nd option the best. But all would return an error if there are no duplicate values.

Comment: @JvdV yes thanks for pointing this out. The user can use **IFERROR** to return the desired output if an error is not an option.

Comment: second one is very effective and simple. quite liked it

Answer (score 5):

This formula would do the job:

```
=MODE(LARGE(A2:E2,ROW(1:5)))
```

[image]

---

It would work in a few stept; first `ROW(1:5)` returns an array of numbers to evaluate with `LARGE` so it would look like > `=MODE(LARGE(A2:E2,{1,2,3,4,5}))`. Next, `LARGE` will put the range in order of 1st largest to 5th largest so it would look like > `=MODE({3,2,2,1,1})`. Now `MODE` can pick up the largest most frequent value.